# Auto complete pushes other div down. Need help to make a scroll auto complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a input box that has autocomplete however suppose there are 100 entries that match the value it displays all and pushes other div all the way down. I need help on how to make a like display up to 5 only then make it possible to scroll to other values. Hopefully all I need to change is in the css part.

Here is my input box. Note this is inside a table:

```
<input type='text' id='text_lot_number' name='text_lot_number'>
<div class="results results_lot_number"></div>
```

Then here is my script part. This is inside document.ready:

```
$("#text_lot_number").keyup(function() {
    var keyword = $("#text_lot_number").val();
    if (keyword.length >= MIN_LENGTH) {
        $.get( "autocomplete.php", { keyword: keyword, method: 'LOTNUM' } )
        .done(function( data ) {
            $('.results_lot_number').html('');
            var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $(results).each(function(key, value) {
                $('.results_lot_number').append('<div class="item">' + value + '</div>');
            });
            $('.item').click(function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                $('#text_lot_number').val(text);
                $('.results_lot_number').hide();
            });
            $('.results_lot_number').show();
        });
    } 
    else {
        $('.results_lot_number').html('');
    }
});
```

autocomplete.php just contains the suggestion in array. For simplified form let's use this:

```
<?php
$aryAutoComplete = array("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4");
echo json_encode($aryAutoComplete);
```

This is what it looks like: 
[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: use style="overflow: scroll" on the div

Comment: I added it in the results div. It has a scroll bar but cannot scroll since it still displays all entries. Is there a way to limit the entry say 5 or 10?

Comment: Never mind I found the answer: I used max-height. Thanks for the answer this fixed my problem. Please post an answer so I can choose that as an answer for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `style="overflow: scroll"`

```
<div class="results results_lot_number" style="overflow: scroll"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must set a `max-height` of however many pixels, 5 list items are together, then set `overflow: scroll;`.

So for example:

```
.results {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Also here is a fiddle with all of it together: https://jsfiddle.net/s4dm0jaw/